# Replacing try/catch with Task.ContinueWith

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement a logic that will first check the cache for some values and if there is no cached values, the API will be called. For now, I have the following working implementation:

```cs
public class CourseRepository
{
  private List<Course> _cache = new();
  
  private async Task<List<Course>> GetCoursesCache()
  {
    if (_cache.Count == 0)
      throw new Exception();

    return _cache;
  }

  private async Task<List<Course>> GetCoursesApi()
  {
    var responses = callApi();

    if (responses != null)
      _cache.AddRange(responses);

    return responses;
  }

  public async Task<List<Course>> GetCourses()
  {
    try
    {
       return await GetCoursesCache();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      return await GetCoursesApi();
    }
  }
}
```

Now, while this works, I do not see myself maintaining that when I have 3+ data sources (eg: cache, api, local database). So, I would like to replace that with ContinueWith, if possible. I've tried the following:

```cs
public Task<List<Course>> GetCourses()
{
  return GetCoursesCache()
    .ContinueWith(
      t => GetCoursesApi(),
      TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
    ).Result;
}
```

But when the client actually `await GetCourses`, it does not seem to return anything, even if the API gets called properly.

Any feedback on ContinueWith or other Implementations are welcomed. I'm just trying to get the first non failing task's result.

Comment: If it returns, it must return something.

Comment: Have you thought about using [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynclazy-1?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Can you provide an example? I'm interested

Comment: Before I do that, can you tell me where there is actually any underlying async calls in the code? The code you posted doesn't actually need `async` and it could just use the normal `Lazy<T>` type as far as I can see,

Comment: @MatthewWatson mainly in GetCoursesApi. The `callApi()` is actually awaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ... not really what `ContinueWith` is intended to do, so *in terms of the existing API*: what you already have is better; but: better doesn't mean "good". In particular, forcing `Task` allocations every call *even if the value is already known*, and forcing the async machinery: is a *lot* of unnecessary overhead. There's also some thread safety issues here re the list being accessed concurrently, and using an exception to indicate "no value" is very inefficient.

Suggestion: make this *way, way simpler*:

```cs
private Task<List<ShareAble.Shared.Proto.ShareAble.v1.Course>>? _cache;
public Task<List<ShareAble.Shared.Proto.ShareAble.v1.Course>> GetCourses()
    => _cache ??= GetCoursesApi();

private async Task<List<ShareAble.Shared.Proto.ShareAble.v1.Course>> GetCoursesApi() {...}
```

whenever possible, this now returns the *same* `Task<T>` instance to all callers, lazily instantiating it. This works because `Task[<T>]` can be awaited by *any number of callers* (unlike `ValueTask[<T>]`, importantly). There's still a thread-race in the scenario where two threads call `GetCoursesApi` *when it is null* (i.e. the first time); this *can* be fixed in multiple ways, but: in reality this is probably fine. It *does* mean that if the `GetCoursesApi()` call *fails*, everyone will always see that failed result, so you might want to be able to reset the cache, which is as simple as setting `_cache = null;`.

---

A second approach would invole `ValueTask[<T>]`, some kind of `TryGetCache(...)` check, etc - but honestly: it probably isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Not sure on how you would set the _cache in the GetCoursesApi though. Should I create a task that simply returns a list? Or maybe a Task.FromResult?

Comment: @ClémentJean you don't - look carefully: `=> _cache ??= GetCoursesApi()` which means (roughly): `if (_cache is null) { _cache = GetCoursesApi(); } return _cache;` - it assigns `_cache` the first time it is fetched; note that we aren't *awaiting* it here - we're letting the caller deal with that; we're saying "has a task been started? if so, return that (without caring whether it is started, incomplete, etc) - otherwise: start it, assign to that, and return it"